# How To click each of the sliding banners

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When there a series of sliding banners , and we need to  click each of them and get back , how is it posible with the help of selinium code , can anyone help for this .

Comment: What code are you testing? With what code are you testing it?

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to find the right selector. Our combine Selenium with some visual testing tool like Kantu Browser or Sikuli. In that case, using a screenshot of the ">" arrows is enough.